# Understanding rails active record association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was reading a book for agile web development and I found this code

application controller

```
  private    
  def current_cart
    Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
    cart
  end
```

line items controller

```
def create
  @cart = current_cart
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:product => product)
  respond_to do |format|
   if @line_item.save
     format.html { redirect_to(@line_item.cart,
            :notice => 'Line item was successfully created.') }
```

I don't understand the  following two lines

```
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:product => product)
format.html { redirect_to(@line_item.cart,
       :notice => 'Line item was successfully created.') }
```

`@cart` holds the value of `cart_id` then what `@cart.line_items` point and what is the use of build method here?

Also what `@line_item.cart` means here? which action will be called?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's start with `@cart`. As phoet says, it is not a simple integer. It is set by `Cart.find(session[:cart_id])`, so it is an instance of the `Cart` model based off a row in the database.

The `Cart` model presumably inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` which has all the logic for has_many (and other) associations (relations) between models. So, I would expect to see at least

```
def Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :line_items
end
```

in the `Cart` model.

So, when you call `@cart.line_items` you get something that is conceptually a list of that cart's line items through the association set up by the call to `has_many`. Calling `build` on that results in a new (as of yet, unpersisted) instance of the `LineItem` model that has its `cart_id` value set to `@cart.id`.

I hope that clears things up a bit. Rails associations are tricky business.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is not correct. `@cart` holds a `Cart` object from the `current_cart` method. It's either new, or the one held in the session.

So `@cart.line_items` works with the `has_many` relation of `Cart` and `line_items.build` will setup a new `LineItem` to be saved to the database on `@line_tem.save`.